# Implementing generic java interface adds additional method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a generic java interface `Id<T>` with a single method `T getId()` and a class `MyClass` that implements `Id<Long>`. When I inspect the methods declared on `MyClass` using java reflection, I see two methods: one with return type `Long`, and one with return type `Object`. Where does the second method come from and how can I remove it?

Here is the source:

```
package mypackage;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method method : MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println(method);
        }
        // prints out two lines
        // public java.lang.Long mypackage.MyClass.getId()   <-- ok
        // public java.lang.Object mypackage.MyClass.getId() <-- not ok
    }
}

interface Id<T> {
    T getId();
}

class MyClass implements Id<Long> {
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return new Long(0);
    };
}
```

Comment: In a method with Returntype `Long` you can also return a primitive `long` e.g. `return 0L;`. It will be autoboxed to a `Long`. Not a answer to your question, but maybe you didnt know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second method is a `synthetic bridge` method, you can check it with `method.isSynthetic()` or `method.isBridge()`. You can't remove it, but if you don't want to see it in the list of declared methods, just check all those methods to have `isBridge() == false`.

Synthetic bridge methods are added automatically to generic classes during compilation. You can read more about synthetic methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

```
for (Method method : MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println("Method: " + method);
    System.out.println("synthetic: " + method.isSynthetic());
    System.out.println("bridge: " + method.isBridge());
}

// 1
//Method: public java.lang.Long Main$MyClass.getId()
//synthetic: false
//bridge: false
// 2
//Method: public java.lang.Object Main$MyClass.getId()
//synthetic: true
//bridge: true
```

Answer (score 2):

This is feature. Same issue was raised in

[JDK-8060179 Class.getDeclaredMethods() returning inconsistent results with generics](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060179) and closed as 'not a bug'.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the compiled methods by `javap -c MyClass`:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
class MyClass implements Id<java.lang.Long> {
  MyClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public java.lang.Long getId();
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/Long
       3: dup
       4: lconst_0
       5: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/Long."<init>":(J)V
       8: areturn

  public java.lang.Object getId();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #4                  // Method getId:()Ljava/lang/Long;
       4: areturn
}
```

As you can see there are **2** methods for `getId`, one **return type** is `Long` as `implementation` and the another **return type** is `Object` type (it's invoking the `Long getId` method).

The **return type** `Object` **method** is for handling when no specify the **generic type** and bridge to `Long getId` method. Example:

```
    Id<Long> id = new Id<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long getId() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    Long id1 = id.getId();
```

as the above code snippet we can implement the `Id` anonymous class with the `Long` type. but the problem we also can implement the `Id` anonymous class like without specify **generic type** in variable:

```
    Id id = new Id<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long getId() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    Object id1 = id.getId();
```

so for now the compiler can't infer **generic type** for variable `id`, when `id.getId()` it's returning type `Object` type variable, it means it's calling this method `public java.lang.Object getId();` and  bridge to `public java.lang.Long getId();` method.